# Psake - How to activate /m switch for MSBuild?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, psake

Hi I'm trying to compile my project using MSBuild & Psake but I have problems passing the /m to MSBuild. Here is my code:

```
Exec {
    MSBuild $solutionFile "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;OutDir=$tempPath /m"
}
```

MSBuild Output:

> "C:\Users\mabre\Source\Psake\Psake.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "C:\Users\mabre\Source\Psake\src\Psake.Library\Psake.Library.xproj"
>   (default target) (5) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5):
>   error : Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\mabre\Source\Psake.build\temp
>   **\m**\src\Psake.Library\obj\Release\netstandard1.6'.
>   [C:\Users\mabre\Source\Psake\src\Psake.Library\Psake.Library.xproj]
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 4 Error(s)
> ```

Note that the **/m** is part of the output path now

> Error: 7/22/2016 12:39:04 AM:  At
>   C:\Users\mabre.nuget\packages\psake\4.6.0\tools\psake.psm1:156
>   char:17  +                 throw ("Exec: " + $errorMessage)  +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Exception: Exec: Error
>   executing command         MSBuild $solutionFile
>   "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;OutDir=$tempPath
>   /m"   . Build exit code: 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try putting the `/m` first instead of last, so it doesn't get affected by what Psake might add after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it without putting all of the arguments in one string.  Here are two examples of what my MSBuild tasks look like in pSake:

```
Task CleanProject -depends RestoreNuget {
    Exec {
        msbuild `
            "$VisualStudioSolutionFile" `
            /target:Clean `
            /property:Configuration=$Configuration `
            /verbosity:quiet
    }
}
```

and...

```
Task BuildProject -depends DeleteBinAndObjFolders {
    Exec {
        msbuild `
            "$ProjectPath" `
            /target:Rebuild `
            /property:Configuration=$Configuration `
            /property:OutDir="$ProjectBuildArtifactsPath" `
            /property:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True `
            /property:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False `
            /property:WebProjectOutputDir="$WebBuildArtifactsPath" `
            /verbosity:quiet
    }
}
```

Note that I put `"` around any variables that I think may contains spaces.

So try something like this for yours:

```
Exec {
    MSBuild "$solutionFile" /p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;OutDir="$tempPath" /m
}
```